# My Nginx Server is not running my App on my domain name?? Please give me solution

Tags: nginx, vps

When I open the IP Address http://45.82.75.190/

I see the default Nginx Page and not my app I have successfully proxied my node.js app which is running on port 5000 to run or port 80 but still my app is not running in browser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFQAq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDHOM.png)

Comment: Please add the output of `nginx -T` to the question so we can see the full configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your `nginx` is configured to respond to a specific server name but you are accessing it with an IP so it is showing you the default page.

Comment: can you solve my issue bro I will provide my username and password to solve my issue plz I can give you and after that I will change my password plz

Comment: plz guide me what changes I need to make in what files to solve my issue

Comment: if you open freemediatools.com it is still showing the default nginx page